# Command + F2 has stopped enabling Target DIsplay Mode

Tags: imac, target-display

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to enable Target Display Mode (using a Thunderbolt cable between my two iMacs) has mysteriously stopped working. I have a new iMac and an older iMac (late 2012) both running 10.13.4.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/325451/edit) your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do? I *assume* you're wanting to use your late 2012 iMac as a display for your new iMac. Is that correct? Also, what exact model of iMac is your new iMac? Also, when you say *stopped working*, does that mean you've had this working previously between these two particular Macs? Finally, did this change coincide with anything else (new software, new hardware, etc)?

Comment: So it used to work before? Or did it never?